# In the category Ab, the product and coproduct coincide $(C_1 \times C_2 = C_1 \oplus C_2 = C_1 \coprod C_2)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

> In **Ab**, the product and coproduct coincide $(C_1 \times C_2 = C_1 \oplus C_2 = C_1 \coprod C_2)$

I'm not exactly sure how I'd show these two objects in the category **Ab** are the same.

I've tried using the commutative diagrams from the definition of product and coproduct, but I can't see how to show this equality.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Obviously you'll need to use some properties of the category itself, not just the definitions of product/coproduct, as it is not true in a general category.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Z$ be a product of two objects $X,Y$ in a pre-additive category with projections $p:Z\to X$ and $q:Z\to Y$.
By universal property of product, there exists $i:X\to Z$ and $j:Y\to Z$ such that $ip=1_X$, $iq=0$ and $jp=0$ an $jq=1_Y$.
Let  $h=pi+qj:Z\to Z$.
Then $hp=p$ and $hq=q$ thus $h=1_Z$.

We claim that $Z$ is a coproduct of $X,Y$ with inclusions $i,j$.
For let $x:X\to W$ and $y:Y\to W$.
Then $z=px+qy$ is the only morphism such that $iz=x$ and $jz=y$.

Comment: This post is old, and I'm not sure why the OP never responded, but (1) I think you mean $ip = 0$ and $jq = 0$ and (2) Why do these equations hold, i.e., why is it the case that composition of these morphisms yield zero morphisms? I'm not seeing how.

Comment: The equations are correct and they holds by universal property of product.

Comment: By $iq$ do you mean $i \circ q$? It looks like $q: Z \to Y$ and $i: X \to Z$, so that these aren't composable morphisms. Also, the universal property of a product only guarantees the existence of $i: X \to Z$ such that $i \circ p = 1_X$; it says nothing about zero objects (unless in the context of abelian categories it says more; I'm learning about these, hence my ignorance and visit to this page).

Comment: I mean $iq=q\circ i$; the existence of a such $i:X\to Z$ such that $ip=p\circ i=1_X:X\to X$ and $iq=q\circ i=0:X\to Y$ holds in every pointed category.

Comment: Oh I was starting to suspect you might be using that notation! I was also unaware of that fact of pointed categories; thanks for your help.