# How to show that a finite direct sum is isomorphic to a finite direct product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum

Our teacher told us that a finite direct sum and a finite direct product are isomorphic. Is there a simple way to prove it?

Comment: In which context? This is not true for sets, for instance.

Comment: For a simple proof in pre-additive categories see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2440387

Comment: This is, to my mind, a more subtle issue than it appears. There is a question, for example, of in what sense the isomorphism is natural, and also in what sense it is unique. See https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/ for a careful discussion.

Answer (score 1):

For $R$-modules this is true, so in particular for abelian groups. A short proof uses that the category of $R$-modules is *additive*. Hence finite direct sums and finite direct products coincide, because the direct sum corresponds to the coproduct, and the direct product to the product.

Reference at MSE: see the above comments, and

[The direct sum $\oplus$ versus the cartesian product $\times$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39895/the-direct-sum-oplus-versus-the-cartesian-product-times)